# Same item indent for flushleft inside tcolorbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize, tcolorbox

I want to use itemize (or enumerate) where some items use an environment that basically amounts to flushleft inside a tcolorbox. They get another indent for the item marker, as seen for #4 here. I can "fix" it by adding some empty text first, as for #5, but I would like a better fix (and understanding of what happens.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item normal
\item \begin{tcolorbox}[box align=center] box \end{tcolorbox}
\item \begin{flushleft} flushleft \end{flushleft}
\item
  \begin{tcolorbox}[box align=center]
    \begin{flushleft} flushleft inside box \end{flushleft}
  \end{tcolorbox}
\item
  \mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[box align=center]
    \begin{flushleft}
      fixed
    \end{flushleft}
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What you want to achieve is not very clear. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: That the 4 in the example is aligned with 1, 2, 3.

Comment: So it implies this tcolor box should be wider than the others? Or maybe each tcolorbox should start at the left margin and include the enumerate label?

Comment: Instead of using the `flushleft`environment  you could instead use `\raggedright` or `\RaggedRight` with the `ragged2e` package.

Comment: In the actual problem I use an environment that uses flushleft, but after trial and error I could see that this was the relevant part. Yes, I can try to create a variant of that environment. But I don't understand why the combo moves the position of the label (especially since there is no problem with either #2 or #3.

Comment: @pst: Yeah, I don't understand why using `flushleft` environment causes the problem either. My comment was more so that you could obtain the desired results while waiting for an explanation.